# Is there a way to loop through selected columns in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I have a table TestTable with columns of col_test1, col_test2, col_test3 ...
and I want to create a loop that accesses each of these columns individually and find the max value and place it in the variable made in the declare block and simply dbms.out.put it.

```
Declare 
    my_array sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('col_test1','col_test2','col_test2');
    v_test number(8,0);
Begin
    for r in my_array.first..my_array.last 
    loop
        select max(my_array(r)) into v_test from TestTable;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    end loop;
End;
/
```

The output I get is just the string 'col_test1'which should be 50.
This is done through oracle SQL. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is a weird requirement. You need to be executing the `max` query dynamically as you don’t know the column until execution time, for this you would use `execute immediate` usually. That `rownum` filter looks very out of place, what do you want it to achieve?

Comment: Ah that rownum filter was from a previous test to just return 1 row, shouldn't be there so will remove from the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL for this

```
Declare 
    my_array sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('col_test1','col_test2','col_test2');
    v_test number(8,0);
Begin
    for r in my_array.first..my_array.last 
    loop
        execute immediate 'select max(' || my_array(r) || ') from TestTable'
                     into v_test;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
    end loop;
End;
```

If you're going to resort to dynamic SQL, however, it would generally make more sense to build a single SQL statement that took that `max` of all three columns in one pass rather than potentially doing three separate table scans on the same table.